# Empty browser window still exist even HttpServletResponse committed

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

Window1 -> `one.jsp`, from this jsp , we are calling one more jsp (Window2) to generate pdf by `window.open("two.jsp?x=y")`. By doing this it opens `Two.jsp` and generate the pdf as well , finally that window2 get closed. But the scenario is, the copy of Window1 still exist in the view with empty content even `HttpServletResponse` gets committed.

Code in `Two.jsp`:

```
File NewFile=new File(outpath);
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int)NewFile.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(NewFile);
fis.read(fileData);
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(fileData.length);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"Sample.pdf\"");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(fileData); 
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
fis.close();
```

Currently we are migrating from JBOSS 4.0.2 to JBOSS 6.0 , The above code is working fine in JBOSS 4.0.2. Is this issue related to JBOSS 6.0? Kindly help us to come out from this issue.
Expecting your valuable suggetions.